# Why my android studio increase memory after some build times?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I build simple hello work default project in android studio.
When open:
[image]

and first times
[image]
appear two java process and first java increase memory.
and it continue increase memory follower time
[image]
It occupy my RAM and I can't do anything. What happen here and any solution for case? Thanks all!

Comment: did u try cleaning cache ?

Comment: I try clean cache too, but it still remains, I can end task sub java task. But main java still increase.

Answer (score -1):

You can try ssd instead of normal hard disk.
100 % you will get output

Comment: Your answer is too vague, Please provide more detail. Please read the SO guidelines before posting.